# Using CDKv2 with TypeSCript giving error ts2345

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to learn TypeScript and CDKV2.

```
test.ts
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { teststack } from '../src/teststack';
const queueName = 'input-queue';
const app = new cdk.App();
new Task2Stack(app, 'teststack', { queueName: queueName });
```

```
teststack.ts
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';

export interface getStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  readonly queueName: string;
  env: {
    account: '123456789012',
    region: 'us-east-1'
  }
}

export class teststack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: getStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here

    // example resource
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, '.....', {
      visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
      queueName: props.queueName,
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
Error:

Argument of type '{ queueName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'getStackProps'.
  Property 'env' is missing in type '{ queueName: string; }' but required in type 'getStackProps'.ts(2345)
teststack.ts(7, 3): 'env' is declared here.
```

Question: If I remove/comment env it works fine. Is it possible to convert getStackProps to a function so that I can eliminate this error ?
What is causing this error ?
**Can anyone please explain ?**

Comment: It's great you are contributing questions to SO.  Could you also contribute feedback on the answers you have received?  I see you have not accepted answers to your last 7 questions.  Upvoting/accepting encourages those who take time to answer and helps the wider community find good content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this error ?

The error message says it all: the stack constructor requires an object of type `getStackProps`<sup>*</sup> as the 3rd argument, but you are not providing one. It's missing the required `env`.

> Can anyone please explain ?

`account: '123456789012'` does not define a default account.  Rather, it's a very narrow type parameter.  The account *must be* `123456789012`.  Any other value will cause a compiler error.   Here's an illustration ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2ryoPboFAbiwBOyAhgMbwAqsAzuAMrhUDWACiTtPaKAG98-ErHII8AG0igAjgFdYigHLkAtrABcoRiQwBzANzDQsdADdtQ-vyqUc89OG0ByAIwAmAMwAWAKwAbADsABwAnAAMni4ANCYisPq46K7y9AC0Yozpbi4mAL74hfggoADyANL49uiMoPo4OAhcPPTadIws7C28oAC8giYKSrCqGtoARGqQ6cOK6ejqsBNx-GaWgzagdg5Orp6+gaGR0as2okl4qRlZ4Dl5-IXFpfZq0KiSpKYk3CQAhCUwDQYPAXFNyCQMhdkhMXKBUHx0DhwNt6PRUPpFgAjT4QHAQEGgMFpTLkbJuWHVPB1LHiHptUAdZisSicbi9AbWOSKFRLSbTWY82ALJYrEzrKzxbaUeyOZxEg7+YLhKIeWJS6FXIlqCFQxLJB6gJ5AA)) where I try to pass a value other than `us-east-1` to `region`.  As expected, the TS compiler complains:

```js
// type definition - what is allowed?
interface TestStackProps  {
  queueName: string;
  env: {
    account: '123456789012',
    region: 'us-east-1'
  }
}

// OK
const goodProps: TestStackProps = {
  queueName: "my-queue-name",
  env: {
    account: '123456789012',
    region: 'us-east-1'
  }
}

// compiler error!
// Type '"mars-region"' is not assignable to type '"us-east-1"'
const badProps: TestStackProps = {
  queueName: "my-queue-name",
  env: {
    account: '123456789012',
    region: 'mars-region'
  }
}
```

> Is it possible to convert getStackProps to a function so that I can eliminate this error ?

No.  Not the right approach.

---

* By convention TS capitalizes type names and class names.  `teststack -> TestStack`, `getStackProps -> TestStackProps`.

Comment: I understand the problem now.Thx! Since I have defined env in the interface so when calling it is expecting the env. Really, appreciate if you could help me with a solution as it will help me understand better.

Comment: @Judi Pass `goodProps` (mutatis mutandis, from the answer's code block) to your constructor instead of `{queueName: queueName}`.

Comment: As you had already mentioned that the way I have defined account is a very narrow type parameter. When I try to pass the real account, I will get error. Is there another way of fixing this or I should follow the recommendation in the  documentation of cdk - (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html)

Comment: I have completed Upvoting/accepting.

Comment: @Judi  You did not say what error you are getting.  Did you forget to change the dummy`123456789012` to `account: "<your-account-num>"` in the props interface definition?  Narrow types are fine - as long as the prop values match!  You can also have a more relaxed  `account: string` interface to accept all strings.  Or omit `env` from your interface entirely, as `cdk.StackProps` already defines an (optional) `env`.  It's your call.

Comment: All three options suggested by you works.